# Issue with saving undefined table columns with pandas to_sql

Tags: python, sqlite, pandas

I would like to save tabular data into a sqlite database using pandas. I defined a minimal set of columns to be in the database, but would like to allow the possibility of having additional columns saved. The problem I encounter is that with

```
with sqlite3.connect(dbname) as cnx:
   df.to_sql("InboundOrders", cnx, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

I can save additional columns, for example an undefined column named "Description". While using the "append" option

```
with sqlite3.connect(dbname) as cnx:
   df.to_sql("InboundOrders", cnx, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

I get the usual sqlite error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: table InboundOrders has no column named Description
```

I was expecting that for the first data insertion into the table, the two options would behave the same way. I would like to "append" new data to the database, as I expect to come back at it with more data at a later time, but this issue is causing me trouble. Is this an unwanted feature, or is it supposed to be this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bug. `DataFrame.to_sql(..., if_exists='append')` tries to insert rows from your DataFrame to the existing table, so if that table has for instance 3 columns and your DataFrame has 4 columns, you will receive that expected error, because SQLite expects only three columns.

In other words `if_exists='append'` allows you to append rows, NOT columns.

As a workaround you can add a column to SQLite table first (manually, using SQLAlchemy, etc.) and then you can use `DataFrame.to_sql(..., if_exists='append')` method.

**UPDATE:**

Demo for NOT existing tables:

```
In [68]: cnx = sqlite3.connect('c:/temp/a.db')

In [69]: df
Out[69]:
   binary   text1   text2  text3
0       1   hello    this  table
1       1   cider    that  chair
2       0     bee     how  mouse
3       0  winter  bottle    fan

In [70]: df.to_sql('test_replace', cnx, if_exists='replace')

In [71]: df.to_sql('test_append', cnx, if_exists='append')

In [72]: pd.read_sql('select * from test_replace', cnx)
Out[72]:
   index  binary   text1   text2  text3
0      0       1   hello    this  table
1      1       1   cider    that  chair
2      2       0     bee     how  mouse
3      3       0  winter  bottle    fan

In [73]: pd.read_sql('select * from test_append', cnx)
Out[73]:
   index  binary   text1   text2  text3
0      0       1   hello    this  table
1      1       1   cider    that  chair
2      2       0     bee     how  mouse
3      3       0  winter  bottle    fan
```

Comment: I understand the logic. However, I found it weird that if the table does NOT exist yet (as in my case) the two options would return a different behaviour. Wouldn't one want them to behave the same way the first time a table is filled?

Comment: Please note that I rephrased the question to make my use case clearer

Comment: @famargar, i can't reproduce described by you behavior for NOT existing tables. Both options are working properly in case the table does NOT exist